# Add Gesture Recognizer to specify object of cell in table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

im trying to add a gesture recognizer to an uiimageview in all cell that will make the uiimageview on that indexpath to change the image, but i cant figure out how to tell the gesture ibaction to change the image in that indexpath.

what i achieve with this code is that it only work fine in the last cell, all other cell not getting the gesture also.

my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...
    imgConfirm = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:107];
    [imgConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"]];
    [imgConfirm addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureM2];
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)tapGestureTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSData* imgConfirmData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgConfirm.image);
    NSData* imgConfirmData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"]);

    if ([imgConfirmData1 isEqualToData:imgConfirmData2]) {
        [imgConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]];
    }
    else{
        [imgConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"]];
    }
}
```

im sorry if the question have been asked before :) but i search for hour but cant find the proper one.

*edit: in this code, every cell got the tap recognizer, but the ibaction is not fired

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
indexpath=[self.tableViewM2 indexPathForCell:cell];
// Configure the cell...
UIImageView *imgConfirm = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:107];
[imgConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"]];

UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
// setup gesture as needed
[imgConfirm addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
return cell;
}

- (IBAction)tapGestureTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLog(@"%d,%d",indexpath.row,indexpath.section);
UIImageView *imgConfirm = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
NSData* imgConfirmData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgConfirm.image);
NSData* imgConfirmData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"]);

if ([imgConfirmData1 isEqualToData:imgConfirmData2]) {
    [imgConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]];
}
else{
    [imgConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"]];
}
}
```

*Edit2: i finally found out how to do it, the code from below is correct, but need tell the gesture the action to fire!

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureTap:)];
```

Comment: Please note that you end up adding multiple gesture recognizers to each image view as the user scrolls the table view and cells get reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the image view from the gesture. There is no need to use an instance variable for `imgConfirm`. You also need to create a separate gesture recognizer for each image view. You can't reuse the same one over and over.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...
    UIImageView *imgConfirm = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:107];
    [imgConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"]];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] inittWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureTap:)];
    // setup gesture as needed
    [imgConfirm addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)tapGestureTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UIImageView *imgConfirm = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
    NSData* imgConfirmData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgConfirm.image);
    NSData* imgConfirmData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"]);

    if ([imgConfirmData1 isEqualToData:imgConfirmData2]) {
        [imgConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"]];
    }
    else{
        [imgConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon2"]];
    }
}
```

One important piece missing here is that if the user scrolls the table, the image will be reset. You need to add more code to keep track of the current state of each image so your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` sets the proper image.

Comment: Need to `reloadTableData` or `tableviewcell` after change image.

Comment: @ViralSavaj No you don't.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it seems still not working for me, the thing that its only work for the last cell...the setimage work fine for all cell, but addGestureRecognizer only got in the last, the method also :(

Comment: Oops. You need to create a new gesture recognizer for each cell. You can't add the same gesture to every row. I'll update my code.

Comment: thanks, now it got gesture recogonizer for every row, but now none image is changed @-@ im not sure whats wrong, i add a nslog to the ibaction then i found that the whole ibaction is not fired

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question with your latest code (as an update, don't replace the original code in the question).

Comment: thanks, its because that the code haven't tell the action that the gesture should fired, now it works!

Comment: sorry for bother again, but what u said is true that the image is reset after its out of view, could u tell me what should i do to save the state of it?

im still quite noob at objective c :D only started a month ago

Comment: That's a big enough topic for you to post another question on.

Comment: well i did search and find that the question is already been answered, i actually could make an array to retain the cell state (only 0 and 1) , only not sure how to get the indexpath value outside the cellforrow method.